# IN en CASE en un WHERE

Tags: sql-server, usecase

Tengo una sentencia donde dependiendo del tipo de Fuente (Reporte o mail) buscara el tipo de mail (Correo_1 o Correo_2), pero si el tipo de Fuente es "Reporte" entonces busque en ambos tipos de correos, pero al correrlo no me busca nada, necesito ayuda para este problemilla.

Aquí esta mi codigo:

```
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME, @Date DATE, @Fase VARCHAR(35), @Fuente VARCHAR(10), @IN VARCHAR(40);
SET @Date       = GETDATE()-1;
SET @ToDate     = DATEADD(day, 1, @Date);
SET @Fase       = 'Correo 1'
SET @Fuente     = 'Reporte'
SET @IN         = (''''+'Correo 1'+''''+','+''''+'Correo 2'+'''')
```

```
WHERE 
     [InsertDate] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @TODate
     AND 
     [Tipo_Mail] IN (CASE WHEN @Fuente = 'Reporte' 
            THEN (@IN)
            ELSE @Fase
     END)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo esto hay varias formas de resolverlo la mas sana es que uses una función para hacer un split de tus datos y así poder seleccionar lo que requieres

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo, la otra manera seria que lo hagas con código rojo pero la verdad no le veo el caso de hacerlo así.

```
--Declaración de variables 
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME, @Date DATE, @Fase VARCHAR(35), @Fuente VARCHAR(10);
SET @Date       = GETDATE()-1;
SET @ToDate     = DATEADD(day, 1, @Date);
SET @Fase       = 'Correo 1'
SET @Fuente     = 'Reporte'

DECLARE @FromDate DATE=GETDATE()

DECLARE @HelpTable TABLE(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
InsertDate DATE,
Tipo_Mail NVARCHAR(50)
)


INSERT INTO @HelpTable VALUES(GETDATE(),'Correo 1'),(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()),'Correo 1'),(GETDATE(),'Correo 2')


IF @Fuente='Reporte' --Verificamos si es reporte en ese caso seteamos que Fase es igual a los dos de caso contrario solo se queda con correo 1
BEGIN 
SET @Fase='Correo 1,Correo 2'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
SET @Fase = @Fase 
END

SELECT * FROM @HelpTable
WHERE 
     [InsertDate] BETWEEN @FromDate AND @TODate
     AND 
    Tipo_Mail IN (SELECT value FROM dbo.fn_Split(@Fase,','))
```

En el ejemplo esta para crear la funcion. :D

Puedes jugar con el ejemplo cambiando @Fuente por otra palabra y veras que solo devuelve resultados con correo 1.

Ejemplo:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c4e55790cb3a1919daf61b27eb720940

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación, para bien y mal no podía crear funciones por permisos pero ya existía una igual, funciono justo como esperaba y tu esfuerzo ayudara a mas para un futuro, nuevamente, gracias.

Comment: Solo una duda jeje... en caso que desee que @Fase si sea lo que envié como variable de usuario y no como valor predefinido (por lo de "correo 1"), tendrás algún ejemplo?

Comment: Cierto, esa parte no mencione, este query se ocupa para un SP que ejecuta un SSIS, para ello la varible @Fase es algo que se ocupa dinámico de acuerdo a lo que el usuario pondrá en el SSIS

Comment: Listo, era: 
IF @ Fuente='Reporte'
BEGIN 
SET @ Fase='Corre 1,Correo 2'
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
SET @ Fase = @ Fase
END

Comment: Ya veo que bien Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Así se construyen los cases en sql:

```
CASE
    WHEN [Tipo_Mail] IN (CASE WHEN @Fuente = 'Reporte 'THEN (@IN)
    WHEN ... THEN ...
    ELSE @Fase
END;
```